# Format response to friendly parsed json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, web-scraping

So i have some web scraping coming back like this:

```
["SEvent({\"event_id\":\"ID\",\"date\":\"Sat  5 Nov 2016, 19:30\",\"suppress_b...
```

Now what im wanting is to render this in a parsed json. This is how my render looks at the moment:

```
 respond_to do |format|
       format.json  { render :json => {:testing => price1}}
     end
```

However this returns this:

```
{
  "testing": [
    "TMEvent({\"event_id\":\"ID\",\"date\":\"Sat  5 Nov 2016, 19:30\
```

How do i make it so that it looks better, (more like this):

```
SEvent:{
event_id: ID,
date: Sat  5 Nov 2016, 19:30}
```

(if i place this code into jsonformatter it works and looks exactly how i wanted it!)

Any help?
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Use `pretty_generate` function

Example:

`require 'json'
my_object = { :array => [1, 2, 3, { :sample => "hash"} ], :foo => "bar" }
puts JSON.pretty_generate(my_object)`

Comment: Hi there, This didn't work, I tried the puts and got the exact same back